# Bootstrap dropdown button does not unwrap on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

While I was working on my Ruby on Rails project I faced this problem. I tried to implement dropdown button, exactly as it was done on [their site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/). However the button doesn't seem to work as intended. It doesn't respond to clicks and raises some error in the browser console, which I have no idea how to interpret:

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._menu.classList')
```

Here is the application.html.erb code, which contains links to both **bootstrap.min.css** and **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**, which as I know need to be included for correct dropdown work (I know that bootstrap should be imported from a separate file, but I couldn't figure out the way to do it properly):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title><%= full_page_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('beast_hack_favicon.png') %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= yield(:page) %>">
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

And there is the navbar code, which should contain working dropdown:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-md shadow fixed-top px-2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <%= link_to "BEAST Hack", root_path('#'), class: 'navbar-brand text-white fw-bold' %>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Новости", news_path, class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Задания", tasks_path, class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Команда", team_path, class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Личный кабинет", account_path, class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "О нас", root_path('#'), class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
            <% if current_user.role == 'admin' %>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Управление
                </a>
              </li>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Посты", moderator_posts_path, class: 'nav-link text-white dropdown-item' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Участники", moderator_users_path, class: 'nav-link text-white dropdown-item' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Команды", moderator_teams_path, class: 'nav-link text-white dropdown-item' %></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Панель управления", admin_control_panel_path, class: 'nav-link text-white dropdown-item' %></li>
              </ul>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "О нас", root_path('#'), class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Партнерам", root_path('#'), class: 'nav-link text-white' %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex nav navbar-nav navbar-right w">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= button_to "Выйти", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete,
                        data: { turbo: false }, class: 'btn btn-outline-light btn-nav mx-1' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= button_to "Вход", new_user_session_path, method: :get,
                        data: { turbo: false }, class: 'btn btn-outline-light btn-nav mx-1' %>
          <%= button_to "Регистрация", new_user_registration_path, method: :get,
                        data: { turbo: false }, class: 'btn btn-outline-light btn-nav mx-1' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 70px"></div>
```

JQuery is also installed, via Gemfile

```rb
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Any ideas, where might be the problem?

I searched for similar problems but in every case the problem was that they couldn't include **bootstrap.min.css** and **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** correctly or did it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The menu item "Управление" seems to be supposed to toggle the submenu, but it doesn't because the submenu is outside the `li` item. Make it look like this:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <!-- a tag with the text "Управление" -->
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- li items here -->
  </ul>
</li>
```